# How do I reference a config file in Scala WorkSheet and Akka?

Tags: scala, akka, config, worksheet

I'm trying to create a simple akka system in Scala Worksheet but each time I try, I get this error.

```
com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'akka'
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKeyOrNull(tsets.sc:148)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKey(tsets.sc:141)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findOrNull(tsets.sc:168)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(tsets.sc:180)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(tsets.sc:185)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getString(tsets.sc:242)
at akka.actor.ActorSystem$Settings.<init>(tsets.sc:166)
at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.<init>(tsets.sc:533)
at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(tsets.sc:139)
at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(tsets.sc:116)
at #worksheet#.system$lzycompute(tsets.sc:9)
at #worksheet#.system(tsets.sc:9)
at #worksheet#.get$$instance$$system(tsets.sc:9)
at A$A9$.main(tsets.sc:35)
at #worksheet#.#worksheet#(tsets.sc)
```

Even though the Scala worksheet is in the exact same directory as the `application.conf` file.

The akka entry for the file looks something like this.

```
akka {
  loglevel = ??
  actor {
    provider = ??
 }
 remote {
log-remote-lifecycle-events = ??
enabled-transports =??
netty.tcp {
  hostname = ??
  port = ??
  maximum-frame-size = ??
  maximum-frame-size = ??
  send-buffer-size = ??
  send-buffer-size = ??
  receive-buffer-size = ??
  receive-buffer-size = ??
}
  }

  cluster {
roles = ["frontend"]
seed-nodes = ??
use-dispatcher = c??

failure-detector {
  threshold = ??
  acceptable-heartbeat-pause = ??
  heartbeat-interval = ??
  heartbeat-request {
    expected-response-after = ??
  }
  }
 }
}
```

I have even tried adding this to the build.sbt

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("application.conf") => MergeStrategy.concat
}
```

Comment: Have you put your `application.conf` into `resource folder`?

Comment: The application.conf and worksheet are both in the resources folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the possible variants is calling `ConfigFactory.parseFile` with `resolve` (if you have some substitutions like `receive-buffer-size = ${send-buffer-size}` in your config file):

```
val confPath = getClass.getResource("/application.conf")
val config = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File(confPath.getPath)).resolve()
config.getString("akka.loglevel")
```

Your `application.conf` file should be in `resources` folder and your worksheet can be placed in `scala` folder.

**Update**

If you use Intellij IDEA. There is a [workaround](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-9229) for this

1. Go to *File > Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Scala > Worksheet*
2. Untick *"Run config in the compiler process"* and press *"OK"*

[image]

So you can use `ConfigFactory.load()` freely

[image]

I used IDEA with version **2018.1.5**

Comment: The `application.conf` file is in the `resources` folder. I've tried before doing it with the worksheet in the `scala` folder and I get the same error. I don't understand the importance of the possible variant with `resolve`. What is it doing?

Comment: `resolve` is needed when you need resolve substitutions in your config file. Suppose you have when you assign to variable value of another variable in the same config using this syntax `receive-buffer-size = ${send-buffer-size}`. Otherwise you'll get `ConfigExceptionNotResolved`

Comment: In `ConfigFactory.load()` it is called automatically, but in this case you need to call `resolve` if you have some subtitutions with `someVariable = ${anotherVariable}` syntax

Comment: Thank you. Changing the worksheet settings worked for me.